# Custom drop down using tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drop-down-menu

I have been searching for quite a while to find out easiest way to create custom dropdown menu for my app but it seems like there is no native support from Apple to do so , Is there any way to achieve it with minimal work and less complexity because my each single screen will have lots of drop down ?

**The result I want to achieve**

[image: Drop Down]

[image: Drop Down 2]

Comment: Sorry dude but you have to make custom by your own. I have also tried many libraries for it. But all are not stable with devices size. You need to present a VC which shows Tableview and takes data to reload on it. Also you reuse that VC on any screen.

Answer (score 1):

so first of all you need to create a view controller in story board or Xib with the class and then with this method below you will present the view controller based on the size that you want and also the location to show the table
remember you have to design every things in that view controller

```
    let vc = YourTableViewController() // the view that you want to present
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = yourView // can be button or view that you want to open the drop menu from that 
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = yourView.bounds
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .any]
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 340, height: 185)
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in here the `YourTableViewController`  is the drop menu view controller which has the table view and cells and etc . and the `yourView` is the view or button that you clicked and want to see the drop menu under that
also you can set the size as you see in the codes

Comment: But bro how would i customize it as per my image above?

Comment: with the size you can set the size of the page that you want and also the YourTableViewController is a view controller or table view controller with a list of the items that you want